# How to use enrichment (external) call during iterating over streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it OK to use enrichment (external) API call during iterating over a stream?

For example, the following code snippet:

```
User[] fullUsers = plainUsers.stream().map(user -> {
        user.setComments(restAPI.getUserComments(user.getId()));
        return user;
    }).toArray();
```

Here we see a call to some external *restAPI* system to fill the field in User entity.

Is this approach fine or we should a different approach once dealing with enrichment/external systems?

Comment: Do you see a problem?

Comment: Yes, I don't like the side effect, that we modify the object during the iteration, but actually there is one more offtopic problem with many dedicated external calls but it's not in the scope of the current problem.

Comment: @agurylev To solve the other problem, you should look into changing the REST API to accept bulk data and get corresponding response back which could be of the form `Map<String, List<String>> getUserToCommentsResponse(Set<String> users)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams are a functional idiom, and functional code should strive to be immutable and free of side effects. It's not a good practice to modify stream items. It's technically possible, but I would definitely flag it in a code review.

The purpose of `map()` is to transform objects into new objects. It's not to modify the existing objects in place. It's a code smell that you're returning the very object that was passed in.

I would recommend using `forEach()` instead. It's designed to have side effects.

```
plainUsers.forEach(user -> user.setComments(restAPI.getUserComments(user.getId()));
User[] fullUsers = plainUsers.toArray(new User[0]);
```

Alternatively, an explicit `for` loop works just as well:

```
for (User user: plainUsers) {
    user.setComments(restAPI.getUserComments(user.getId()));
}

User[] fullUsers = plainUsers.toArray(new User[0]);
```

Comment: …and consider omitting the `toArray` if possible and continue using the already existing collection.